# Run a specific loop in different directories

Tags: loops, unix, directory

I have a loop that I want to run in different directories/folders. 
The directory names are: a, b, c, d, e, ...

My loop is:

```
cd */
for i in Test_*_hit.txt; do cut -f1,2 $i > ${i%.txt}2.txt; done
```

But is not working (No such file or directory), how can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in a b c d e
do
    (cd $i/; for i in Test_*_hit.txt; do cut -f1,2 $i > ${i%.txt}2.txt; done)
done
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, but one (Bourne shell) approach is

```
for d in <directories>
do
  (cd "$d" && <commands>)
done
```

This uses a subshell (the stuff in parens) to change directory & do what you want to do in that directory, which avoids the effort of having to remember which directory you were in.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou It is safer (it doesn't run the loop if the cd fails), but mainly when I started writing it the other one didn't yet exist.